# When to use 相比 and 比?

Tags: word-choice, comparison

I'm not sure to get the difference. If the two following sentences are correct, when should I use one over the other?

**相比:**

> 和打羽毛球相比我更喜欢打网球。

**比:**

> 我羽毛球比网球更喜欢打。

Comment: The 1st one is correct. The 2nd one is not.

Comment: Both sentences are *grammatically* correct, but the second sentence makes no sense. It translates to: *My badminton shuttlecock likes playing more than my tennis ball*.

Comment: How would you make the second one work with 比? If it is possible. And more generally is there a rule to use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy to distinguish.

First is the conclusion:

**"相比" in Chinese equals to "compare with" in English.It's usually a common verb.**

**"比" in Chinese equals to "more than" or "xxxer than" in English.It's usually a comparative form.**

Their usages are quite different.

For example:

> you can use "比" like "我比你高。(I'm taller than you.)" and "相比" like
>   "农村的文化生活无法与大城市相比。(The cultural life in the country cannot compare with
>   that of a large city.)".

Hope my answer helps you.